# Getting WindowManager in CallScreeningService on Xiaomi

Tags: java, android, kotlin, xiaomi

I have a problem with getting `WindowManager` inside some service on some phone models.

I have written service that inherits `CallScreeningService`, I use it to handle incoming calls and draw views on locked screen. On most devices my service works fine, but I found it doesn't work on some Xiaomi devices (for instance Redmi Note 7, Xiaomi MI MAX 3).

Service has problems with getting `WindowManager`:

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
class MyCallScreeningService : CallScreeningService() {

    private var windowManager: WindowManager? = null

    override fun onScreenCall(details: Call.Details) {
        if (details.callDirection == Call.Details.DIRECTION_INCOMING) {
            details.handle?.schemeSpecificPart?.onlyDigits()?.let { phoneNumber ->
                if (phoneNumber.isNotEmpty()) {
                    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                        requestPhoneInfoFromDb(phoneNumber)?.let { phonebookEntry ->
                            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
                                showCallInfoView(phoneNumber, phonebookEntry)
                                respondToCall(details, CallResponse.Builder().build())
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun showCallInfoView(number: String, phonebookEntry: PhonebookEntity) {
        windowManager = getSystemService(Service.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager

        //building view...
    }
}
```

Error happens when I call `getSystemService(Service.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager`, on Xiaomi I get an exception:

> Tried to access visual service WindowManager from a non-visual Context:MyCallScreeningService@ecb7385
> WindowManager should be accessed from Activity or other visual Context. Use an Activity or a Context created with Context#createWindowContext(int, Bundle), which are adjusted to the configuration and visual bounds of an area on screen.
> java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Tried to access visual service WindowManager from a non-visual Context:MyCallScreeningService@ecb7385
> at android.app.ContextImpl.getSystemService(ContextImpl.java:2125)
> at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSystemService(ContextWrapper.java:910)
> at MyCallScreeningService.x(MyCallScreeningService.kt:3)
> at MyCallScreeningService.h(MyCallScreeningService.kt:1)
> at MyCallScreeningService$g.invokeSuspend(MyCallScreeningService.kt:52)
> at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:12)

I have tried many ways to use services's `Context` here or pass it to the service, but I always got the same exception. Hope someone has any ideas about this problem. I can add more details if it will be needed.